# When using datetime -- warning, when using utc_datetime instead -- exception

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

When generating a column of type "datetime" I get a warning

> ```
> the :datetime type in migrations is deprecated,
>   please use :utc_datetime or :naive_datetime instead
> ```

However, when I replace with the type "utc_datetime", I get an exception:

> ```
> ** (Mix) Unknown type `utc_datetime` given to generator
> ```

Comment: Could you please add specific versions of the packages in question for the reference of others who may find your question in the future?

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `:datetime` has been deprecated by Ecto like the warning says, the latest version of Phoenix, 1.2.1, [was released on 12 Aug 2016](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/releases/tag/v1.2.1), before the Phoenix generators [were updated to use the new datetime types on 18 Sep 2016](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/commit/94e38415da40e0b317c30e1d114dd05594955d95). So, until Phoenix releases 1.2.2 or 1.3.0, you'll have to use `datetime` in the generators and manually change the types in the generated migration and schema, or use the unreleased version of Phoenix directly from the master branch of its git repo.

Comment: when will it come out approximately?

Comment: I could not find any info about that unfortunately. It's really been a long time since the last release. They may have announced something in the recent Elixir conferences but I haven't seen the recordings yet.

Comment: If you can work with a release candidate, 1.3.0 rc 2 is happy with utc_datetime. `{:phoenix, "~> 1.3.0-rc.2"}`